# ConcurrentHashMap check then act flow

Tags: java

Does ConcurrentHashMap supports check-then-act sequence or do i need to lock myself? Example:

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    void insertVal(String key, int value){
       if( map.containsKey(key)){
          map.get(key).add(value);
       }else{
          List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
          list.add(value);
          map.put(key,list);
       }
    }
```

The `putIfAbsent` computes value on if its not present there which means this flow is not viable and `putIfPresent`  only if the value is present.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for [`ConcurrentHashMap.compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping). The entire method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this Map.

Your `insertVal` method could look something like this:

```
void insertVal(String key, int value) {
  map.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
    if (v == null) {
      v = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    v.add(value);
    return v;
  });
```

Note there are also related method [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 0):

That is almost the same use-case given as example in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) of `Map.computeIfAbsent()`, which is implemented by `ConcurrentHashMap`:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null (optional operation).
>
> ... The most common usage is to construct a new object serving as an initial mapped value or memoized result, as in:
>
> ...
>
> Or to implement a multi-value map, Map<K,Collection>, supporting multiple values per key:
>
> ```java
> map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<V>()).add(v);
> ```

It can be changed to use an `ArrayList` instead of the `HashSet`:

```java
Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void insertVal(String key, int value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't work correctly for multi-threaded access. For both ArrayList (and HashSet), "If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally." You're not doing that for the call to `add`. If you are going to use `computeIfAbsent` like this, you need to synchronize on the result of `computeIfAbsent`. If you do it as I have suggested, you don't have to explicitly synchronize, because of the happens-before properties documented for ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @Andy good point. Depending on use case, the list can be "wrapped" using `Collections.synchronizedList()`, as suggested by its documentation. That would have the  *advantage* if the list is also changed by other code/thread; or the *disadvantage* of probably being *slower* (mainly if the list is not changed elsewhere)